# F# Circular Type Definition Loop

Tags: class, types, f#, definition

I want to have a type A which has a property which is an instance of type B. And type B has a property of an instance of type A. The problem is, F# reads the source files in order. So if I define type A first, then it won't recognize type B. And if I define type B first, I can't make it have an instance of A. Is there a way around this, or is this just bad design on my part?

Comment: `type a() ... and b() ` - almost certainly a duplicate of something

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question but this article gives a nice overview of the issue: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can a define mutually recursive type if they are in the same file like this

```
type Chicken =
   | Eggs of Egg list
and Egg =
   | Chickens of Chicken list
```